# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple' -python

Tags: python, sockets

I am trying to send a file  from the server to the client using udp. After running the code , i can see a recieved file in the client but no '.txt' extension. If i write something in transferfile.txt i am getting this error : TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple' 
How can i solve it?

Client Code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os

IP = input('enter the ip adress')
PORT = 5050
buf = 2048
ADDR = (IP,PORT)

client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

msg = 'Hello'
client.sendto(msg.encode('UTF-8'),ADDR)
with open('received_file', 'wb') as f:
    print('file opened')
    while True:
        print('receiving data...')
        data = client.recvfrom(buf)
        print('data=%s', (data))
        if not data:
            break
        # write data to a file
        f.write(data)

f.close()
print('Successfully get the file')
client.close()
print('connection closed')
```

Server code:

```
import socket
import sys
import os


IP = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 5050
buf = 2048

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
server.bind((IP,PORT))

data,addr = server.recvfrom(buf)
print(str(addr) + ' says' + data.decode('UTF-8'))

filename='transferfile.txt'
f= open(filename,'rb')
l = f.read(1024)
while (l):
    server.sendto(l,addr)
    print('Sent ',repr(l))
    l = f.read(1024)
f.close()
print('Done sending')
server.close()
```

Comment: In your client code, after printing "receiving data", you need to unpack the tuple response from `client.recvfrom(buf)`. Something like `data, addr = client.recvfrom(buf)`. You're missing the `addr`.

Answer (score 0):

You must decode the data recieved :

```
print('data=%s', (data.decode()))
```